# New to python and need help getting started with this function

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to python and I have done research but all I could find on this problem was on outdated versions of python. I hear this community is able to help me with this problem.

I am attempting on making a function called **makeChange** with **amount** as a parameter.

The function is supposed to take user input as a decimal and convert what the user inputted into bills and coins. (for example .05$, .10$, .25$, .50$ 1$ and so on.)

Is it possible that I can get a base to build off of? (Not the entire function maybe a few errors just so I can learn.)

(Thanks for taking the time to read what I have to say!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

So, in makeChange problem we find try to find the minimum number of coins that add up to a give amount of money.

#### Code

```
def makeChange(amount):
  # You can add more or remove the coins from this list
  coins = [.05, .1, .25, .5, 1]
  # LEARN: Find out how sort function works on a list, and what does the reverse parameter means. Why do we need to sort it?
  # Sort the coins list (incase it's not sorted)
  coins.sort(reverse=True) 

  change = []
  for coin in coins:
    # LEARN: Find out why we type cast the result of totalCoin to integer,
    # LEARN: Find out what do we get by using integer division and modulo to the amount variable
    # Notes: // means integer division, / means float division, % means modulo or remainder
    totalCoin = int(float(amount) // coin)
    amount = amount % coin

    # Round the amount to 2 precision point (0.25, 1.00) since there is no $0.001 right
    amount = round(amount, 2)
  
    # Append the coin we use for change
    for i in range(totalCoin):
      change.append(coin)

    if amount == 0:
      return change

  # If we ever reach here, that means, the given coin in coins list 
  # is not able to return the change
  return 'Not changeable'

print('22.76: ', makeChange(22.76)) # 22.76:  Not changeable
print('13.8: ', makeChange(13.8)) # 13.8:  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.05]
print('2.4', makeChange(2.4)) # 2.4 [1, 1, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05]
```

#### Conclusion

The code above is working properly, I did not any error to it, BUT I added lots of comment for you to find out yourself, how and why this code works the way it is. Good luck on learning Python!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start for you:

```py
def makeChange(amount):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute how many bills and coins are needed. You can work on float type. int function converts float to int and truncate decimal part. For example

```
def makeChange(amount):
    amt = float(amount)
    n100 = int(amt/100.)
    amt = amt - n100*100.
    n50 = int(amt/50.)
    amt = amt - n50*50.
    # and so on... you can add more

    n100, n50 # return how many bills
```